# Story involving a Nanotechnology breakdown

Tags: story-identification, nanotechnology

I am looking for a book that I read awhile ago but can't remember the name or author.  The storyline is basically as follows:

Nanotechnology is taking over the world and the rich are basically immortal. The inventor of nanotechnology lives on his own nanotechnology-made island with his nanotechnology-enhanced children. His one son has a severe allergy to any form of nanotechnology. Towards the end of the book the nanotechnology starts to break down and all the medical apparatus that kept the people alive break down, as well as whole cities built by nanotechonology.

Answer (score 3):

The Last Mortal Man by Syne Mitchell (Deathless book 1)

In the twenty-fourth century, nano-designed biology has turned the world into humanity's playground. And entrepreneur Lucius Sterling has created a trillion-dollar empire solving the world's problems: poverty, disease, war, and even death. But when a new technology attacks the fundamental building blocks of nano-biology, the survival of humanity is at stake.And only Sterling's estranged grandson, Jack, can stop the destruction.

It was supposed to be the first in a series but "According to her blog, Mitchell's The Last Mortal Man series has not been chosen for further publication. As a result, she has chosen to pursue other series."